# Qt C++ Mapping coords to create QGraphicsItem in scene on mouse pos

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I want to add new ellipse (custom `QGraphicsItem` which is movable) on mouse position. How to map coords to ellipse item to get right position on scene ? For example from `contextMenuEvent` I get `QPointF coords =  event->scenePos();` and there I want to create ellipse. I have custom `QGraphicsScene MyScene` where I have pointer to `QGraphicsView* view`.

I use `event` form `void MyScene::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event)`

`QPointF coords = event->scenePos();`

`QPointF ellpiseCoords = view->mapToScene(coords.x(), coords.y())`

I always get wrong transform. How should I mapToScene coords from `event->scenePos()` to get correct coords in scene where I will be able to create Ellipse on `QRectF(ellpiseCoords.x(), ellpiseCoords.y(), 50, 50);` as a `boundingRect()`

Comment: What is wrong with the transform? QT's coordinate system origin is at the upper left corner of the ellipse. Do you expect it to be at the center?

Comment: Ellipse item is movable and when I create object on  `QRectF(ellpiseCoords.x(), ellpiseCoords.y(), 50, 50);` I can't control it every time when I try to move item. And it appears on wrong pos in scene.

Comment: Please reformat your question, it is quite unclear what you wan to ask.

Comment: `event->scenePos()` should give you the correct coordinates. Your second mapping just throws them off.